# r - Disabling code chunk highlighting in Bookdown (RMarkdown) theorem environments

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

So I'm using `RMarkdown` with the `Bookdown` extension to take notes in math classes. `Bookdown` has [several pre-defined math environments](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#theorems) to include and auto-number `theorems`, `definitions`, `proofs`, etc.

These are implemented as special code chunks in RMarkdown; for example, this chunk with the `{theorem}` header renders the text as a theorem in the output

````
```{theorem}
Here is my theorem.
``\`
````

The issue I'm facing is that `RMarkdown` seems to be treating the text inside the body as code, and as a result, several convenient features of the `RMarkdown` editor do not work here. For instance, one cannot click on inline math to get a preview pop-up, and inserting a `'` (like in variable names such as `x'`) highlights the rest of the body in green (presumably because the editor thinks its the beginning of a string).

Is there a way to get the editor to treat the `Bookdown` math environments as regular text instead of code? Alternatively, is there a way to create special headers for math environments (like maybe `# (thm) Pythagorean theorem`)?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you say "the editor", do you mean the R GUI or RStudio code editor?

Comment: Yes, what editor are you actually talking about? RStudio?

Comment: I'm using RStudio. Sorry for not mentioning that in the post.

Comment: I don't think this is possible... this is an implementation issue bookdown uses code blocks to render the correct output, but rstudio handles it like code and thus doesn't pase it like normal text.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Will using a different editor solve this issue? Alternatively, can I create custom headers for theorems, proofs, examples, etc.?

Comment: FYI the next version of **bookdown** will allow you to used fenced Divs to write theorems: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-bookdown-version-021 Then the content won't be syntax highlighted.

Comment: @YihuiXie Thank you! That will be great. I've starred the repo you linked.